# Creating "Histogram" From input of X values and Probability Estimates in R

Tags: r, plot, bayesian, dirichlet

***Background***

I'm trying to replicate something like the following plots from the chapter on the Dirichlet Process in "Bayesian Data Analysis" by Gelman et. al.  The images depict a stick-breaking process.

The plots effectively show you a probability distribution for four different scenarios.  On the horizontal axis are the "data" values and on the vertical axis are the probability estimates associated with that data.

[image: Desired]

***My Problem***

I think I already have the data necessary to create the plots; the data points and the corresponding probability estimates (yes, the probabilities are actually of small intervals around the points, since it's a probability density function).  The problem is I don't know how to make a plot containing nice bars like those above.  Normally in R, histograms are built from vectors of just data values, but I have two columns. (and searches haven't revealed anything)

```
## data
head(dat)
    thet prob.estim
1 -0.1532657 0.05451808
2 -1.2471313 0.06407723
3  0.3452990 0.06608997
4  0.4886357 0.12634090
5  1.3894174 0.02572439
6 -0.7041029 0.03688599
```

The closest I can get just looks bad.  See the code and the image below.
(Note the probability estimates are different due to use of random number generation)

```
# Best I can do, but not bars
plot(dat$thet, dat$prob.estim, main = "Alpha = 1")
```

[image: Best I can do]

Answer (score 1):

First, generate some data to work with:

```
set.seed(24601)
thet <- seq(-3, 3, by=.05)
prob.estim <- rbeta(length(thet), 1, 100)
dat <- data.frame(thet = thet,
                  prob.estim = prob.estim)
# putting in the spike in the plot
dat[thet == 1, ]$prob.estim <- .99
```

## Generating the plot, with base graphics

First, here's the scatterplot version (so you can see how the data I generated compare to yours)

```
plot(dat$thet, dat$prob.estim)
```

[image: scatter]
And here it is as a barplot

```
barplot(names.arg = dat$thet, height = dat$prob.estim)
```

[image: bar]

## Generating the plot, with ggplot2

If you're interested in controlling the appearance of your plot (which it sounds like you are), you may want to move to ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(y = prob.estim, x = thet)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image: bar_ggplot]

Comment: Thanks.  But this doesn't work for me.  For the ggplot, I just get an empty plot window. The barplot works if I sort by thet first, but I can't adjust the axes.  The axes automatically go from like -4 to -3, even if I try to change xlim. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the data. For ggplot, can you confirm that the data are saved in a dataframe (`dat` in the example), and both `thet` and `prob.estim` are numeric? To check, use `str(dat)`